# Use same chart across multiple canvas

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How can I use the same chart to be rendered across multiple canvas. I want to create one ChartJs object and assign it to multiple canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, what you can do is create 1 config object and call `new Chart` multiple times each time with another canvas id.

Other solution is to create the chart once and call `.toBase64Image()` on it and set that as an image source for multiple images so that you only have to create your chart once but can show it multiple times